# How many strings of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ of length $n$ are there such that $0$ appears exactly once and $1$ appears an even number of times?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

> How many strings of length $n$ of the digits $\{0,1,2,3\}$ are there such that $0$ appears exactly once and $1$ appears an even number of times?

My attempt: define $a_n$ to be a sequence of such string.

If I had only the even number of appearances constraint, then it would be:

$a_n =\\\begin{cases}0(\text{no constraint})= a_{n-1}\\ 
1 (\text{even number of ones}) = 1 (\text {general sequence}) - 1(\text{even number of ones}) = 4^{n-1}-a_{n-1} \\
2 (\text{ no constraint})= a_{n-1}\\
3 (\text{ no constraint})= a_{n-1}\\\end{cases}$

So: $a_n=4^{n-1}+2a_{n-1}$

If I had only the other constraint then I get stuck pretty quickly:

$b_n =\\\begin{cases}0& (\text{ no more zeros})= 3^{n-1}\\ 
1& (\text{no constraint}) = \begin{cases} 10(\text{ no more zeros})= 3^{n-2} \\
11= ? \\12=? \\13=? \end{cases}\\
2& (\text{ no constraint})= ?\\
3& (\text{ no constraint})= ?\\\end{cases}$

Combining the two constraints makes it too complex to turn into a recurrence...

Note that it should probably be solved with a recurrence formula.

Comment: Where $n$ is the length of the sequence?

Comment: @SolidSnake yes, I'll add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $c_n$ be the number of such strings of length $n$. Then since $0$ appears once, we have $c_n=na_{n-1}$, where $a_k$ is the number of words of length $k$ over $\{1,2,3\}$ in which $1$ occurs an even number of times.

You know how to find a recurrence for the $a_k$, and probably how to solve it.

Comment: I see, pretty neat. Is there a way to turn $a_k$ to be expressed with $c_n$ or vice versa? I haven't seen how to handle two kinds of sequences when solving the recurrence.

Comment: Well, the relationship  $c_n=na_{n-1}$ can be turned into $a_{n-1}=\frac{c_n}{n}$, but that is not profitable. I am now sorry I used these letters, should have let $a_n$ be exactly as in your post, and $b_k$ be the number of strings of length $k$ over $\{1,2,3\}$ with an even number of $1$'s.

Comment: Once you have (in the notation of my answer) a formula (not recurrence) for $a_k$, you can write down an explicit formula for $c_n$ using $c_n=na_{n-1}$.